# NoMethodError in View - Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, paperclip

When I try to present an uploaded in my Home view, I get a NoMethodError. Here's the error text:

> NoMethodError in Items#home
>
> Showing C:/Users/User/My Documents/portfolio2/app/views/items/home.html.erb where line #4 raised:
>
> undefined method `main' for nil:NilClass
>   Extracted source (around line #4):
>
> ```
> <% @items.each do |item| %>
>     <div class="row">
>         <div class="large-12 columns panel">
>             <%= image_tag @item.main.url(:thumb) %>
>             <h3><%= item.title %></h3>
>             <p><%= item.content %></p>
>       </div>
> ```

Here's what my model looks like:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name("users")
  attr_accessible :main
  has_attached_file :main, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change `@item` to `item`, so it should be:

`<%= image_tag item.main.url(:thumb) %>`